# Javascript slider jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        controlNav: false,
        animation: "fade",
        startAt: 0,                     
        slideshow: true,                
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
    });     
});
</script>
```

Why doesn't my slider work? I copy pasted it from an other script so I am clueless where to start.

Comment: Well, where's the relevant HTML?

Comment: Have you included the `flexslider` plugin (and jQuery) before this script?

Comment: with given information, the first thing I would say check the developer tools console for whatever browser you using, that there is no javascript error.

Comment: Yes everything is included though Luc's answer helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the comma after `slideshowSpeed: 7000,` and you are good to go ;)